# Selenium testing - checkbox "element not interactable"

Tags: java, selenium, testing

Trying to select element for testing. We have it's ID, so:

```
   @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "tree-node-home")
    WebElement CheckBoxMenuItem;
```

Throws error: `"element not interactable".`

Same with XPath or selecting by css `[type='checkbox']`

Tried to defer loading:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("tree-node-home")));
```

But this time I got
`"java: <identifier> expected"`
with the cursor blinking before `(ExpectedConditions".`

What the F.?

Comment: Does it time out when you use a `FluentWait` instead of a `WebDriverWait`? You can initialize it `withTimeOut(Duration)` while `pollingEvery(Duration)` and put, let's say, 30 seconds for timeout?

Comment: Can you post the url if it is public?

Comment: Sure, it's https://demoqa.com/checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click the parrent label instead of the checkbox.

Code:

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class DemoQACheckBoxTest extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // wrapped driver init
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/checkbox");
        WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("tree-node-home"));
        WebElement checkBoxLabel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@for,'tree-node-home')]"));
        System.out.println("checkbox text: " + checkBox.getText());
        System.out.println("label text: " + checkBoxLabel.getText());
        System.out.println("checkbox is displayed: " + checkBox.isDisplayed());
        System.out.println("checkbox is enabled: " + checkBox.isEnabled());
        System.out.println("checkbox is selected: " + checkBox.isSelected());
        checkBoxLabel.click();
        System.out.println("checkbox is selected: " + checkBox.isSelected());
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 16990
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Pro 10, 2021 2:23:39 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
checkbox text: 
label text: Home
checkbox is displayed: false
checkbox is enabled: true
checkbox is selected: false
checkbox is selected: true
```